# Django Sha2-512

Tags: python, django, sha512

I'm trying to integrate Django with CKAN. 
For now i have password compatibility problem.

```
CKAN passwod sample: 
"pbkdf2_sha256$20000$ccNI0alYkFxm$JX5g4w9pd0SaRuviKespQBdv21vI0XLVxF4or7KmxYM="
Django password sample:
"$pbkdf2-sha512$19000$ZYxxbi1FCKHUmnOuFWKslQ$d.4ND4lr/.PnfFVWcTnm.Byhi08GS29TNXqaMj/x6E6OKMmZJCqd.o21THbGDVrwsUGpC9U1IemVWijKNtVToA"
```

They use different hashing method. The idea is to switch Django password hashing. I find sha2-512 in Django source, but how can I activate it?

Package django_sha2 wont work for django 1.8/Python 2.7
Also i found https://gist.github.com/simonwhitaker/4474381 this code, but where can i implement it?

**UPDATE**. So i add it to my code, and import like this:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'ckan_user.hasher.PBKDF2SHA512PasswordHasher',
...
)
```

Now i have this:

```
# django:
# "pbkdf2_sha512$20000$UjhMbV0VRLZo$BH0h5i+NDm15siMwnydGFOSt24szp1kGqMVppuIMDpsMyquYESh0GHzRA6rUfEnDKi5aKdd5VoxYVB9bG0ymdA=="
# ckan: 
# "$pbkdf2-sha512$19000$ZYxxbi1FCKHUmnOuFWKslQ$d.4ND4lr/.PnfFVWcTnm.Byhi08GS29TNXqaMj/x6E6OKMmZJCqd.o21THbGDVrwsUGpC9U1IemVWijKNtVToA"
```

The last problem is - change default django password format:

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

(add '$ at beginning') and switch number of iterations to 1900. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Switching iterations should be as easy as setting the `iterations` attribute on your hasher.

```
class PBKDF2SHA512PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    iterations = 19000
```

Prepending a dollar sign at the beginning is going to be trickier. For writing the password, you might be able to overide [`make_password`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L58), call `super()` and prepend a dollar sign. However, you will then probably have to monkey patch the [`identify_hasher`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L58) internal method, because Django doesn't expect a dollar at the beginning of an encoded password.

Comment: There's not a simple answer for the password format. I've updated my answer with some suggestions to try. Good luck!